# Why do I get different results with these two queries in Application Insights Anaytics?

Tags: analytics, azure-application-insights

I want to get the number of unique users in the last 24h. I came up with these two different queries.

```
pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(1d) | summarize count() by user_Id | count;

pageViews
| where timestamp > ago(1d) | summarize makeset(user_Id) | extend nb_users = arraylength(set_user_Id);
```

If I run them I get different results for the number of users. Why is that?

Comment: I think I know what seems to be the problem. Lists and sets in analytics seem to be limited to 128 units, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're right and the issue is that by default makeset is limited to 128. 
You can pass another parameter to makeset(user_id, 1000) to change the maximum set size.

However, if you're trying to find the number of distinct users, dcount(user_Id) would be the simplest way (although it's an approximation) or the former method you've used would give you the most accurate results.